# Access JSON values from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The click handler is accessing a data attribute on the element and setting a variable based on what is it, in this case 'option1'. I want to use the name of this variable to access a JSON object. But in the example it's returning 'undefined', as if it's looking for an array called 'thisOption'. How can I use this data attribute to bring back the correct JSON content?

```
// Note: thisOption returns "option1", which is correct.

jq = jQuery;

// Pass info
jq('.button').click( function() {
    var thisOption = jq(this).data('name');
    jq('#subscriptions .price').text(thisOption.monthly);
});

var option1 = {
    "name"      : "Super Pack",
    "monthly"   : "€10",
    "yearly"    : "€100",
    "gift"      : "Free €20 voucher"
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `option1` is in the global scope then you can access it via the window object with a dynamic key:

```
jq('#subscriptions .price').text(window[thisOption].monthly);
```

The `[]` notation allows you to use variable property or key names.

Comment: Great, thanks! Why do you need to use the window object to access it?

Comment: If your `jq(this).data('name')` returns different variable names, you can only access them via the window object (if they are global) or if they are contained in another variable/object. In the answer you accepted, the option1 is hardcoded, so if your data-name has option2 it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `option1` like below

```
jq('#subscriptions .price').text(window[thisOption].monthly);
```

Because `option1` is in global scope, you can access it like `window.option1`. When `option1` is a value of some variable, then you should access like `window[thisOption]`

Answer (score 1):

I made some structure so we can see it clearly, you can also check it in jsfiddle.net

Heres the url: http://jsfiddle.net/8hTrr/3/

HTML

```
<a href="#" data-option="monthly" class="button">test</a>
<div id="subscriptions">
    <p class="price"></p>
</div>
```

JS

```
var option1 = {
    "name"      : "Super Pack",
    "monthly"   : "€10",
    "yearly"    : "€100",
    "gift"      : "Free €20 voucher"
};

jq = jQuery;

// Pass info
jq('.button').click( function() {
    var thisOption = jq(this).data('option');
    jq('#subscriptions .price').text(option1[thisOption]);    
});
```